# Resize image and frame with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to add a small profile picture to my navbar, similar to how StackOverflow has on the top. However, when I resize the image for the navbar, it appears that the "container" is still present because when I hover over a part of the navbar that does not include the image, my page acts as if I hovered over the image. How do I fix this?

Image of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZItY.jpg

Codepin of error: https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/ZEWvdwG

CSS:

```
.logo{
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%}
.money{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 6%;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white}
.profile{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  right: 0%}
  .profile img{float:right}
.navbar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328}
  .navbar_links{
    margin-left: 21%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 78%}
  .navbar_links a{
    padding: 1% 1%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;}
  .navbar_links a:hover {background-color: #3F5328}
  .navbar_links span{position:relative; bottom:5px}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo"><a href="../index.php"><img src="http://mrdansby.com/Resources/logo.png" style="width:27%; height:auto"></a></div>
  <div class="navbar_links">
    <a href="../index.php"><img style="width:30%" src="http://mrdansby.com/projects/icons/i_home.png"><span> Dash</span></a>
        <div class="profile"><a href="#"><img src="http://mrdansby.com/Resources/ProfilePics/default.png" style="width:4%;border-radius:50%;object-fit: contain"></a></div>
    <div class="money">$100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `.navbar_links a{` use  `.navbar_links > a{`.  You do not want all `a` to have a hover effect and so on which was affecting the avatar.

see working code below (width makes it appear smaller here)

```css
.logo{
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%}
.money{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 6%;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white}
.profile{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  right: 0%}
  
.profile img{float:right}

.navbar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328}
  .navbar_links{
    margin-left: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 78%}
  .navbar_links > a{
    padding: 1% 1%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;}
  .navbar_links > a:hover {background-color: #3F5328}
  .navbar_links span{position:relative; bottom:5px}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo"><a href="../index.php"><img src="http://mrdansby.com/Resources/logo.png" style="width:27%; height:auto"></a></div>
  <div class="navbar_links">
    <a href="../index.php"><img style="width:30%" src="http://mrdansby.com/projects/icons/i_home.png"><span> Dash</span></a>
        <div class="profile">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://mrdansby.com/Resources/ProfilePics/default.png" style="width:4%;border-radius:50%;object-fit: contain"></a>

            
            </div>
    <div class="money">$100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That definetly gets rid of the ugly bar, but the problem still persists where the "dash" link is not clickable because of the "frame" from the resized image being in the way.

Comment: I updated the code in answer to fix the link issue also. Changed left margin to 30%

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. I should resize the div, not the image. See below.

```
.profile{
  position: absolute;
  width: 4%;
  top: 1%;
  right: 0%}
  .profile img{float:right; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;display: block;}
```